# How to make Selenium Sever not use proxy?

Tags: php, selenium, proxy

I'm trying to run Selenium with PHPUnit on CentOS.  I've been able to do it before quite easily.  this time I'm on a vagrant box, behind a corporate proxy, and I'm having trouble.

When I run PHPUnit, using a Selenium PHP WebDriver, I get this error:

```
Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session from this cache until you have
authenticated yourself.
```

> Generated Fri, 05 Jul 2013 08:43:44 GMT by ClientSiteProxy (squid/2.7.STABLE4)

How can I make Selenium bypass the proxy for localhost?